# duplicate environmental variables when trying to run google cloud run emulator on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run a dockerfile on cloud run emulator.
does anybody know the location of these env. variables? I am developing a plotly dash web app and i am getting errors when I am trying to run it on the emulator. The app runs fine locally on a vnev.

I'm on macosx 13, vscode V. 1.74.3, google-cloud-cli-415.0.0-darwin-arm.tar.gz for macOS 64-bit(ARM64, Apple M1 silicon)

please see the output below:

```
Starting deploy...
- Warning: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[4].name: duplicate name "K_CONFIGURATION"
- Warning: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[5].name: duplicate name "K_REVISION"
- Warning: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[6].name: duplicate name "K_SERVICE"
```

Comment: Have you checked if this documentation on [deploying a service to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/deploy-service#deploying) will help?

Comment: As an aspiring dev I am learning the value of documentation day by day. Thank you.

Comment: So did my comment address your concern?

Comment: I am not done developing, I;ll get back to it later. thank you for your input, I'll be sure to post a feedback when I'm back to cloud run.